# How to get multiple True/False answer lines in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

A cell with 3 lines, like this:

```
print(1)

print(2)

print(3)
```

**returns:**

```
1

2

3
```

and a cell with 4 lines, like this:

```
a = 5; b = 4.5; c = 'house'

isinstance(a, (str))

isinstance(b, (str))

isinstance(c, (str))
```

**returns:**

```
True
```

instead of:

```
False

False

True
```

Why and is there a way of getting True/False answers on each line?

Comment: I believe the way Python works is that it evaluates each statement in order and stops once it yields a result. In your case, `True` is the first result. So Python puts it out and stops.

Comment: In the future, please indicate what you have done before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to print the variables as `isinstance` doesn't actually print. The `True` print is just a preview and not an actual print.

So you have to use:

```
a = 5; b = 4.5; c = 'house'

print(isinstance(a, (str)))

print(isinstance(b, (str)))

print(isinstance(c, (str)))
```

Returns:

```
False
False
True
```